# jquery finding values that match with special characters in them

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><input type='text' id='filter'></td>
   <tr>
      <td id='1'>12345</td>
      <td id='2'>apdfo:ffekl</td>
      <td id='3'>some string</td>
   <tr>
</table>

 $('#filter').keyup(function(){
         var value = $(this).val();
       $('td').each(function(){
           if ($(this).val() == value){
                 //do a thing
           }
       })
 })
```

in the above code, if the user enters the string in any cell into the input, jQuery needs to match the cell and do things.  with this code,  td cell 1(12345) can match, but 2(apdfo:ffekl)  and 3(some string) never do.  I am guessing it is because of the special characters.  how would I go about escaping them?  i can't change the string, because then they would never match what's in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` not `.val()`

```js
 $('#filter').keyup(function(){
         var value = $(this).val();
       $('td').each(function(){
           if ($(this).text() == value){
                 //do a thing
                 $(this).css('color', 'red')
           } else {
                 $(this).css('color', '')

           }
       })
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><input type='text' id='filter'></td>
   <tr>
      <td id='1'>12345</td>
      <td id='2'>apdfo:ffekl</td>
      <td id='3'>some string</td>
   <tr>
</table>
```